# symfony user login restrict to subsite

Tags: security, symfony

I've got a Symfony application that has multiple subsites.
Each site has it's own set of users, but all users are stored in the same table. All users are linked to 1 subsite, never 2 or more.

Allowing a user to use a single account on multiple sites is not an option given the use-case of this website.

I've got a RequestSubscriber which figures out what site is currently being requested (based on hostname) and pushes some extra information into the Request object attributes.

When a user attempts to login Symfony should only attempt to load users from the current subsite, not all users.

I've got a Doctrine Repository class that implements the loadUserByUsername method, but this only receives the requested username.

What would be the best way to adjust my UserProvider so only users from the current site are attempted to be loaded?
Can I configure the security in such a way additional information is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I've already got is to inject the `RequestStack` into the `Repository` class, and use that to add additional parameters to my query.

I would need to write a decorator for the Doctrine EntityManager to make sure it is injected when the Repository is requested, but that is not really a problem.

I don't really like this solution, so I'm looking for better alternatives (if any).